# Programatically click "ok" on msg box?

Tags: javascript, html, extjs

I have a messagebox that has "Ok" and "Cancel". I need to be able to programatically click "ok" using Ext JS  5+. Here's the code to how the messagebox works:

```
Ext.Msg.show({
            title: Your Message Box
            message: Message,
            buttonText: {ok: 'Confirm', cancel: 'Cancel'},
            fn: function(btn){
                 //Do whatever
            }

SOLUTION: Ext.WindowMgr.getActive().query('button[text=ok]')[0].fireHandler();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the solution.

```
 Ext.WindowMgr.getActive().query('button[text=ok]')[0].fireHandler();
```

Answer (score 3):

You can simply call the function, for example:

```
function callback(btn){
    //Do whatever
}

Ext.Msg.show({
    fn: callback
    .
    .
    .
});
```

Now you can call the `callback` function as you want:

```
callback('yes');
```

Comment: I just want to be able to click "OK", don't care about the rest.

Answer (score 1):

You can try use this in callBack function.
when "id=yes",do your action.

```
deleteGridRowConfirm:function(){
    var self=this;
    var confirmMessage = 'Are you sure to delete the selected record?';
    Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Notes', confirmMessage,  callBack);
    function callBack(id){
        if(id=='yes'){
            self.deleteGridRow();
        }
    }

},
```

Answer (score 1):

First create the window assigning it to a variable (or if you identify it by an itemId or a reference just get it with query, lookupReference or whatever method)

```
var myWindow = Ext.Msg.show({
        title: "Your Message Box",
        message: "Message",
        buttonText: {ok: 'Confirm', cancel: 'Cancel'},
        fn: function(btn){
             //Do whatever
        }
});
```

Then if you are interesting just in executing the handler, you can do the following code.

```
var myOkButton = myWindow.query('button#ok')[0];
myOkButton.fireHandler();
```

And if you are also interested in launch the click event for some reason, you can do this:

```
var myOkButton = myWindow.query('button#ok')[0];
myOkButton.fireEvent('click', myOkButton.fireHandler());
```

Comment: What if my button only have text. example:                                                                  buttons: [{
                 text: 'Submit',
                 handler: function(button){ .....

Comment: I think that the code that you wrote, will not show a button if you use Ext.Msg.show. But anyway, if you manage to make it appear, I think that what you could do is add an itemId on the button (like: [{ itemId:'submitButton', text: 'Submit', handler: function(button){}}] ) and then perform a query myWindow.query('button#submitButton')[0]; or something similar.